# differentiable on $\Bbb R^{n}× \Bbb R^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, proof-writing

Let $f : \Bbb R^{n} × \Bbb R^{n} → \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x, y) = x·y$ ,  Show that $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R^{n}× \Bbb R^{n}$ and that $Df(a, b)(x, y) =b · x + a · y$ Here . denotes the dot product.

My Solution:

define $T. (x,y)=b.x+a.y$

Then, $|f(a+x,b+y)-f(a,b)-T.(x,y)|/ ||(x,y)||$ = $|(a+x).(b+y)-a.b-b.x-a.y)|/ ||(x,y)||$= $|x.y|/ ||(x,y)||$

I am unable to proceed any further. What I would like to do is to make $|x.y|/ ||(x,y)||\leq$ something which will go to $0$ eventually and thus the proof follows.
I know that the solution is only about two lines from where I have left but can someone please suggest the inequality in my solution.

Comment: It should help to notice that $|x \cdot y|$ is homogeneous of degree two, while $\|(x, y)\|$ is homogeneous of degree one.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I do not understand what you want to say here.

Comment: If $t$ is a real number, then $|tx \cdot ty| = t^{2} |x \cdot y|$, while $\|(tx, ty)\| = |t|\, \|(x, y)\|$. :)

Comment: @Silvermoon: What about Cauchy Schwarz ??

Comment: @RIchardWilliams: Can Cauchy Schwartz be used here? Please explain how

Answer (score 0):

Your operator $T$ should depend on $(x,y)$.
$$T(x,y)(a,b) = f(x,b) + f(y,a) = b \cdot x + a \cdot y$$
For fixed $(x,y)$ set:
$$A = T(x,y)$$
Now we can say:
$$A(h,k) = f(x,k) + f(y,h)$$
and also:
$$f(x + h,y + k) - f(x,y) = f(x,k) + f(y,h) + f(h,k) = A(h,k) + f(h,k)$$
or:
$$f(x + h,y + k) - f(x,y) - A(h,k) = f(h,k)$$
We have to control $f(h,k)$. For this purpose we set:
$$h = \lambda u \\k = \lambda v$$
This leads us to:
$$\frac{{f(x + \lambda u,y + \lambda v) - f(x,y) - A(\lambda u,\lambda v)}}{\lambda } = \frac{{f(\lambda u,\lambda v)}}{\lambda } = \frac{{{\lambda ^2}f(u,v)}}{\lambda } = \lambda f(u,v)$$
Now result follows with ease because $f(u,v)$ is a constant.
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\lambda  \to 0} \left| {\frac{{f(x + \lambda u,y + \lambda v) - f(x,y) - A(\lambda u,\lambda v)}}{\lambda }} \right| = f(u,v)\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\lambda  \to 0} \lambda  = 0$$